# pg_restore asking for password for database when there isn't one

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I'm setting up a Rails app on a fresh Ubuntu installation and created the Postgres databases using rake db:create:all. In databases.yml, the password field for all databases is left blank. I'm trying to do a pg_restore of a dump I captured from the app's production deployment, but I keep being prompted for a password. I have a feeling this is something to do with the settings in the pg_hba.conf file, but I can't remember how I had them set in my previous Ubuntu installation. How do I get Postgres to trust pg_restore for local connections? Or is there something different causing this issue?

Answer (score 12):

Set `trust` (or `peer` if you want to match postgresql user names to unix user names) for `local` connections in `pg_hba.conf`. You pretty much answered it in your question.

If you're specifying `-h localhost` explicitly then you're using TCP/IP, so you'll need to either omit `-h localhost`, use `-h /tmp` or wherever your `unix_socket_directory` is configured to live, or set `trust` for `host` connections from `127.0.0.1/32` in `pg_hba.conf` as well.

See [`pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) and [client authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html).

Comment: Don't forget to restart the postgre service after this.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to store the login credentials on the client machine in a .pgpass file in the users home directory:

localhost:*:database:username:password

The permissions on this file must be at least 0600 or it will be ignored.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/libpq-pgpass.html